# How to buy using Kucoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want to buy a crypto-currency from Kucoin but there isn't any option like buy using card only options are exchange from coin  A to coin B. How to buy now ?

Comment: For coin to coin exchange, I like the convenience of https://changelly.com and https://www.shapeshift.io

Answer (score 1):

many exchanges are only cryptocurrency-to-cryptocurrency-exchanges. that means: you must buy bitcoin at any other place and then you can deposit it on kucoin, exchange it to another cryptocurrency and withdraw it. you can not pay with fiat-currencies (and you can not deposit/withdraw fiatcurrencies) on this exchange.